# How to stop or uninstall screenly on raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi

As I am implementing digital signage with Dell Monitor.

First thing as I already google there is no option to stop or uninstall screenly & get back to raspberry pi desktop.

I want to know, how we can do that?

> pi@raspberrypi ~ $ /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -s
>   state 0x120016 [DVI DMT (4) RGB full 4:3], 640x480 @ 60Hz, progressive

My monitor maximum resolution is 1920x1200 with 16:10 aspect ratio, why tvservice giving me above mentioned output?

thanks in advanced,

Bhushan Vaiude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is ans:

```
ps aux | grep creen
less ~/screenly/misc/gtkrc-2.0
less ~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml.bak
less ~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml
less ~/.config/lxpanel/LXDE/panels/panel.bak
less /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart.bak
ulink /etc/supervisor/conf.d/screenly.conf
unlink /etc/supervisor/conf.d/screenly.conf
sudo unlink /etc/supervisor/conf.d/screenly.conf
sudo unlink ~/.gtkrc-2.0
ls -l ~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml
ls -l ~/.config/
unlink ~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml
ls -l ~/.config/
ls -l ~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml
ls -l ~/.config/mv ~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml.bak ~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml
mv ~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml.bak ~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml
ls -l ~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml
ls ~/.config/lxpanel/LXDE/panels/panel 
ls ~/.config/lxpanel/LXDE/panels/pane*
mv ~/.config/lxpanel/LXDE/panels/panel.bak ~/.config/lxpanel/LXDE/panels/panel
sudo ls -l /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
sudo ls -l /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart*
sudo mv /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart.bak /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
less /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
#comment xserver-command
sudo     shutdown -r now
```

thanks!